# Good FTP software for Debian desktop for home networks

Tags: debian, ftp

I need a FTP software that I can use in Debian as well as be able to distribute it when I remaster Debian into my own distro. I need it to be able to do both text and graphical but the text based part needs to be optional for the user.

Comment: What investigations have you made into the use of the FTP software bundled in Debian distro ?  Worth adding your findings to your question, together with any initial thoughts on any shortcomings you experienced.

Comment: @steve I found gftp and filezilla... but I'm not sure if they have both text based and graphical based interface...

Comment: OK. Suggest revising your question to replace "good" with your key criteria (e.g. having a text based and graphical interface).  Otherwise you'll just end up with answers where folk post their personal preferences/opinions rather than concise clear answers.

Comment: yep, we don't know what you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion:
**gFTP**

It has both text and graphical interface. See the license, it can be redistributed.